# Fluent Hibernate not returning the required configuration when called from external assembly

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I have an nHibernate Base class and have the function to return the session like this:

```
private static ISession OpenMySession()
{
    var configuration = new Configuration();
    return Fluently.Configure(configuration)
        .Mappings(cfg => {
            cfg.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }).BuildConfiguration().BuildSessionFactory().OpenSession();

}
```

I have domain classes in another project. After opening the session when I try to get the data it is returning null values each time when I called from external application:

```
public static IList<T> GetOjectList<T>() where T : class
{
    IList<T> list;
    try {

        ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria<T>();
        list = criteria.List<T>();

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw;
    }
    return list;
}
```

If I run standard SQL statement using CreateSQLQuery function of session, I'm getting the result set.

I have defined a domain class and mapping in the same assembly and I'm getting the object data using the above function.

I'm assuming that Fluent is unable to resolve the namespace when I call this function from outside this assembly. Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: My guess is that cfg.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()) is to blame. What assembly is OpenMySession in? And what assembly are the fluent mappings in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you should use [Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx) if you want to load mappings from startup project instead of [Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx) . GetExecutingAssembly()  "Gets the assembly that contains the code that is currently executing" so it will be always assembly in which base class is placed.

Comment: Dear @wiero, Great! This has solved the issue. I have googled for the documentation and I didn't get any. Kindly let me know where I can find the documentation. Thanks for the help.

Comment: documentation can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045.aspx but if you enter "class_name msdn" on google if class_name class exists in .net framework you could hit "I'm feeling lucky" to see docs.. but i don't know it is even possible to use this feature this days